# Ordering a SQL query based on the value in a column determining the value of another column in the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

My table looks like this:

```
Value     Previous     Next
37        NULL         42
42        37           3
3         42           79
79        3            NULL
```

Except, that the table is all out of order. (There are no duplicates, so that is not an issue.) I was wondering if there was any way to make a query that would order the output, basically saying "Next row 'value' = this row 'next'" as it's shown above ?

I have no control over the database and how this data is stored. I am just trying to retrieve it and organize it. SQL Server I believe 2008.

I realize that this wouldn't be difficult to reorganize afterwards, but I was just curious if I could write a query that just did that out of the box so I wouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output that you want?  It is not clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT YourTable.*, 0 Depth
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Previous IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YourTable.*, Depth + 1
    FROM YourTable JOIN CTE
        ON YourTable.Value = CTE.Next
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY Depth;
```

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67b89/9) *(Referential integrity and indexes omitted for brevity.)*

We use a recursive common table expression (`CTE`) to travel from the head of the list (`WHERE Previous IS NULL`) to the trailing nodes (`ON YourTable.Value = CTE.Next`) and at the same time memorize the depth of the recursion that was needed to reach the current node (in `Depth`).

In the end, we simply sort by the depth of recursion that was needed to reach each of the nodes (`ORDER BY Depth`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it worked great, and also thank you for the explanation! :) Also thank you to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Oracle`, try `Starts with- connect by`

```
    select ... start with initial-condition connect by 
    nocycle recursive-condition;
```

**EDIT: For SQL-Server**, use `WITH` syntax as below:

```
WITH rec(value, previous, next) AS 
  (SELECT value, previous, next 
    FROM table1
    WHERE previous is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT nextRec.value, nextRec.previous, nextRec.next
    FROM table1 as nextRec, rec
    WHERE rec.next = nextRec.value)
  SELECT value, previous, next FROM rec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [recursive query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), with the one i list here you can have multiple paths along your linked list:

```
with cte (Value, Previous, Next, Level)
as
(
  select Value, Previous, Next, 0 as Level
  from data
  where Previous is null

  union all

  select d.Value, d.Previous, d.Next, Level + 1
  from data d
    inner join cte c on d.Previous = c.Value  
)

select * from cte
```

[fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/352e3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
With Parent As (
  Select
    Value,
    Previous,
    Next
  From
    table
  Where
    Previous Is Null
  Union All
  Select
    t.Value,
    t.Previous,
    t.Next
  From
    table t
      Inner Join  
    Parent
      On Parent.Next = t.Value
)

Select
  *
From
  Parent
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f345d/2)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with a join:

```
select t.*
from t left outer join
     t tnext
     on t.next = tnext.val
order by tnext.value
```

However, won't this do?

```
select t.*
from t
order by t.next
```

Comment: I don't think that this is what op wants. You are basically ordering the rows in ascending order of the `next` value, and op wants it ordered as he shows in the question